# Yii2 - Save data in database without repeating the same page w/ the same ip address

Tags: yii2

I already saved the data i needed in my database, I need to save only one URL on each IP address or user id but it keeps on saving every time I reloaded the page, so I need to get the URL and IP address but only once every page, then after 30 mins w/ the same IP address will be save when visiting the same page again.

Here's my code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?:
($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?:$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']);
        $page_view = new Pageview();
        $user_view = User::find()->where(['id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
        $timedate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $id = Yii::$app->request->url;
        $view_count = Pageview::find()
        ->where(['user_ip'=> $ip])
        ->andWhere(['user_id'=> $user_view])
        ->andWhere(['page'=> $id])
        ->andWhere(['>=', 'date_time', date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('-30 minutes'))])
        ->count();
        if($view_count == 0){
        if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest){    
           $page_view->user_id = $user_view['id'];
           $page_view->user_ip = $ip;
           $page_view->date_time = $timedate;
           $page_view->page = $id;
           $page_view->save(false);  
        }else{
           $page_view->user_id = 0;
           $page_view->user_ip = $ip;
           $page_view->date_time = $timedate;
           $page_view->page = $id;
           $page_view->save(false); 
        }
```

}

Comment: Just check before save if it was saved already for this user in 30minutes by performing one select to DB. You can add some cache per user for avoiding multiple requestes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I already edited my code and it already worked.